# Bootstrap grid column clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a hard time understanding the column clearfix structure in bootstrap.  I'm trying to create a card layout, which needs the rows in the layout to all be the same height, but the content in each entry isn't necessarily the same.  You can see an example of what I'm doing here: https://demo.eap.soa.com/content/test/staticapps.html

Part of the difficulty is that I'm using a handlebars template to produce the content:

```
<script id="Handlebars-Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="row">
  {{#each apps}}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

So it's not easy to insert an empty clearing div every X entries, or even necessarily to know what X is supposed to be.

I can hack it by using a min-height on the col-md-4 class, but that seems pretty ugly.

Any ideas here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this answer can help you.

Your div content is already changing as you said, so a way will be to ask javascript when document is ready.

Just have to check the max height of each targeted div, and apply it at each div.

Here is a kind of code in action : http://bootply.com/103561

Just that, I'm sorry because when I wrote the code, I was in clouds, and the var `mini` is not significative, it should be named '`maxi`'...

And this same code in visu :

```
$(document).ready(  makeDivSimilar  );

function makeDivSimilar()
{
  var mini = 0;
  $('.col-md-4').each(function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).css('height')) > mini )
      {
        mini = parseInt($(this).css('height'));
      }  
  });
  $('.col-md-4').css('height',mini);  
}
```