# set minimum height for div based on height of neighbor column using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm trying to make my own forums and i've decided to start with twitter bootstrap to get myself off the ground.  In the left column is the poster information like the poster's username, the date posted, and any controls like edit, delete, etc when applicable.  the right column is the message posted.  The problem is that if the message is really short the post ends up looking weird like the diagram below:

```
--------------------
|     |            |
|     |            |
|     |-------------
|     |
-------
```

I would like to set the minimum height of the message column to be the height of the poster info column so that for short messages the layout would look more like:

```
--------------------
|     |            |
|     |            |
|     |            |
|     |            |
--------------------
```

here is a snippet of the code i have:

html:

```
<div class="row slight-margin-vert">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="slight-margin-vert">
      <p><strong>Username</strong></p>
      <p><strong>Posted:</strong> 10 minutes ago </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="background-white rounded">
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.background-white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.slight-margin-vert {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20891704/2454790 I think you should do it with javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap grid column clearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891047/bootstrap-grid-column-clearing)

Comment: not exactly the same question but it does have a solution that works.  Thanks for directing me to it.